# Create BP flow to compare data from PDF to XML and from XML to PDF

Tags: blueprism

I have got Requirement is to write a utility to compare Data from PDF à XMLS and XMLà PDF in blue prism.

Comment: Great! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Blue Prism suggests copying your data to the clipboard, then using "GetClipboard" in a calculation stage to move it into your business object. Once you've done that, I'd suggest that you try using the InStr function in a calculation stage to locate the data you're looking for in both the PDF and the XML files. Then you can use the Mid function to pull the relevant information out of the text you're searching through.